# Why is my PL/SQL trigger raising an "Error(2,2): PL/SQL: Statement ignored" and an "Error(2,5): PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' " error?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am attempting to write a trigger which prevents the insertion into my TA (teaching assistant) table if the student is already taking the class for which they're attempting to become a TA. From what I understand the best way to do this (other than a unique constraint, this has to be a trigger) is through the use of rollback, and I'm also using raiserror.

```
create or replace trigger CheckTA
after insert
on TA for each row
begin
if exists (select * from Enrolls where Student_ID = :new.Student_ID and Course_ID = :new.Course_ID) then
rollback;
raiserror('TA enrolled in course as student');
end if;
end;
```

Upon creating the trigger, I'm met with the following errors:

Error(2,2): PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Error(2,5): PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL statement only

The trigger still gets created, but it doesn't trigger when improper values are inserted into TA.

**Tables:**
**TA**

```
Create table TA
(
Student_ID int references Student(Student_ID),
Course_ID int references Course(Course_ID),
Courses_taught varchar2(250),
Office_hours varchar2(25)
);
```

**Student**

```
create table Student
(
Student_ID int primary key,
Name varchar2(50),
Start_began int,
Semester_began varchar2(50),
GPA int,
Degree_status varchar2(25),
Degree_type varchar2(50),
Courses_Taken varchar2(250),
JI_list varchar2(250),
Profile_status varchar2(50)
);
```

**Course**

```
create table Course
(
Course_ID int primary key,
Course_Name varchar2(25)
);
```

**Enrolls**

```
create table Enrolls
(
Student_ID int references Student(Student_ID),
Course_ID int references Course(Course_ID)
);
```

**Stored Procedure**

This is the SP I use to insert TA values that should trigger the trigger. It doesn't raise errors but I'll put it here in case it's relevant.

```
create or replace procedure addTA (s_id int, c_id int, course varchar2)
as
begin
insert into TA (Student_ID,Course_ID,Courses_taught)
values (s_id,c_id,course);
end;
```

Honestly I'm not quite sure what these errors mean, let alone what's causing them, but still I've tried messing with the syntax of raiserror as well as replacing it with raise_application_error with no luck. If anyone could help me resolve or at least explain these errors it would be greatly appreciated. And of course if there is anything obviously wrong with my trigger please let me know.

Comment: Enforcing business constraints like these with triggers is usually a bad idea because they tend to fail in a multi-user scenario. Think about what happens if a second session adds a row to the `enrolls` table, but commits only after the first session has added a row to the `TA` table. A proper UNIQUE constraint is the way to go (you've already mentioned this as an alternative approach, BTW).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says "function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL statement only", meaning that you only can use `EXISTS` inside a SQL statment, while you are using in in a PL/SQL statement.

If you need to check for the existence of some records, you can try something like this:

```
vNum number;
...
select count(1)
into vNumber
from Enrolls
where Student_ID = ...

if vNumber > 0 then
    ...
else
    ...
end if;
```